# Simulate a data transmission timeout

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I have a client-server application written in C#, and I need to simulate a timeout error when sending data over a socket connection (for testing purposes). How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use **Clumsy** (for Windows, https://jagt.github.io/clumsy/) to simulate communication problems as lag, drop, throttle.

It just take place between your application and the network interface.

Comment: I'd prefer just to inject some code into my application, but this can work too.

Comment: An external application will give you better results as it is near to reality. Also be carefull to filter only your application communications, or you whole system will have communication problem!